# Netbeans(java) a Trunk(master branch) file is linked to another branch, then show errors

Tags: object, netbeans, tortoisesvn, branch

Actually I'm working on Trunk, but yesterday I opened a branch to commit something.

Now, my file orderBean.java(on trunk) it's connected to branch.

```
private List<String> getOrders(String data){ 
    List<Object[]> result = orderDao.getResults(data);
    ///...
}
```

line `List<Object[]> result = orderDao.getResults(data);` throws error, getResults() functions does not exist, but actually I have getResults() function on trunk but branch.

Then, I followed the file, and orderDao is linked to branch, thats why it shows that error.

When I build project it shows no error, I think is netbeans or svn Torotise error.

I tried:

- Close and open Netbeans
- Rebuild Netbeans project
- Clean SVN
- Clean Netbeans
- deleting function, close, open and rewrite

but problem persists. It's difficult to work with many error displaying, how can I make work again in correct way my project?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be Netbeans stores cache on System.

- I cleared my workspace cache.
- Close netebeans
- Restart windows

Only this makes it work again, now files are correct linked.

Hope help someone else, I was working 2 days with many error on my code.